# Receiving 500 Server Error with Contact Form Submission.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, error-handling, contact-form

I've looked through a bunch of similar issues but haven't been able to find an answer that works. I recently switched my website over to a different host and am trying to set up the contact form. I am getting a 500 error when I click submit. I've made sure the SMTP is set up correctly. I just don't know what else to try at this point. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
 <form role="form" method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label for="input1">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="contact_name" class="form-control" id="input1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label for="input2">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="contact_email" class="form-control" id="input2">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                    <label for="input3">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="phone" name="contact_phone" class="form-control" id="input3">
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <label for="input4">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="contact_message" class="form-control" rows="6" id="input4"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form
if (!isset($_POST['save']) || $_POST['save'] != 'contact') {
    header('Location: contact.php'); exit;
}

// get the posted data
$name = $_POST['contact_name'];
$email_address = $_POST['contact_email'];
$phone = $_POST['contact_phone'];
$message = $_POST['contact_message'];

// check that a name was entered
if (empty($name))
    $error = 'You must enter your name.';
// check that an email address was entered
elseif (empty($email_address))
    $error = 'You must enter your email address.';
// check for a valid email address
elseif (!preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $email_address))
    $error = 'You must enter a valid email address.';
// check that a phone number was entered
if (empty($phone))
    $error = 'You must enter your phone number.';
// check that a message was entered
elseif (empty($message))
    $error = 'You must enter a message.';

// check if an error was found - if there was, send the user back to the form
if (isset($error)) {
    header('Location: contact.php?e='.urlencode($error)); exit;
}

$headers = "From: $email_address\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address\r\n";

// write the email content
$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content .= "Email Address: $email_address\n";
$email_content .= "Phone Number: $phone\n";
$email_content .= "Message:\n\n$message";

// send the email
//ENTER YOUR INFORMATION BELOW FOR THE FORM TO WORK!
mail ('EMAIL', 'Young & Company - Contact Form Submission', $email_content, $headers);

// send the user back to the form
header('Location: index.html'/*.urlencode('Thank you for your message.'*/)); exit;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `PHP` error log. Try this to show errors.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Post your logs here if you can't discern which logs are relevant. Most likely SMTP settings are be blamed. mail function opens a socket connection. using SMTP settings.

SMTP settings can be managed through ini or by:

```
ini_set('SMTP', 'smtphost');
ini_set('smtp_port', 25);
```

The above settings are just, for example, you need to have your own SMTP settings. For example, if you have a Gmail account, you may use it to send mail. It depends on your specific situation on which SMTP server you may want to use.

Here are the [Gmail SMTP settings](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server). Also, look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on the last line of `contact-form-submission.php` file.
You forget to remove the extra bracket from the below line.

Old

```
// send the user back to the form
 header('Location: index.html'/*.urlencode('Thank you for your message.'*/)); exit;
```

New

```
// send the user back to the form
header('Location: index.html'/*.urlencode('Thank you for your message.'*/); exit;
```

Or include that bracket in comment tag.

```
// send the user back to the form
header('Location: index.html'/*.urlencode('Thank you for your message.')*/); exit;
```